# Conditionally building/modifying a nested array of objects

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to build a menu based on user permissions. Here's a simplified example of the above mentioned array:

```
this.model = [
    {
        label: "Admin",
        items: [
            {
                label: "Users",
                icon: "fas fa-list",
                routerLink: ["/admin/users/"],
            },
            {
                label: "Clients",
                icon: "fas fa-list",
                items: [
                    {
                        label: "List",
                        icon: "fas fa-list",
                        routerLink: ["/client/list"],
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Create",
                        icon: "fas fa-list",
                        routerLink: ["/client/create/"],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

This array is responsible for generating the menu tags in its respective component, like so:

```
<ul class="layout-menu">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of model; let i = index;">
        <li app-menuitem *ngIf="!item.separator" [item]="item" [index]="i" [root]="true"></li>
        <li *ngIf="item.separator" class="menu-separator"></li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Now, I have a series of user permissions stored in `sessionStorage` as booleans for access. I need to use these permissions to either add or subtract items from the menu based on them.

For example, if "canCreateClients" is false, then the "/client/create/" part of the menu should not appear.

I have a general idea of how to use ternary operators to apply conditional values in JSON, but this is an array of objects that can be nested indefinitely due to dropdown menu items, so it would end up having nested operators too.

I can solve the issue by creating the entire array in a temporary variable, then individually remove each object based on permissions. However, this very impractical.

What would be a good solution for this?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by "build" here: what conditional values would you be using ternaries for? What would you be removing "based on permissions"?   The answer for working with arbitrary tree structures usually involves the word recursion, but it's hard to know what to suggest without understanding what it is you're specifically trying to do here.

Comment: Attempted to clarify the question and expand the code a bit, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A robust general-purpose solution for this type of scenario is probably overkill. The way I would approach this is to include the necessary permission booleans in the site map data, and have the render template compare the required permission and the user's permissions to decide whether to render that particular item.

So an individual item might look like

```
{
   label: "Create",
   icon: "fas fa-list",
   routerLink: ["/client/create/"],
   permissionReqired: "canCreateClients"
}
```

and your render code could, as it's recursing through each item of the tree, compare the contents of the "permissionRequired" key with the array of the particular user's permissions.  I'm rusty enough in Angular that I'm not going to try coding it out but the pseudocode would be along the lines of

```
usersPermissions= ['canCreateClients', 'canDoTheThing'] // loaded from user data somewhere

if (!item.permissionRequired || usersPermissions.includes(item.permissionRequired)) {
  // render the item
}
```

That way you only have one tree to worry about, all the various permission requirements are documented inside it, and the render code doesn't have to include a lot of conditions, it just needs to compare a field to an array and see if they match.

Comment: I hadn't thought of this, thank you! Even though the rendering template comes from a library, I can go there and add further conditions while using the extra value in the objects to handle visibility.